# can't click a link after event.preventDefault

Tags: javascript, android, events, cordova

#### Question:

At a project(phonegap at android), I listen the touch event as MDN [guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Touch_events#Example):

```
document.addEventListener("touchstart", handleStart, false);    
function handleStart(evt){    
     evt.preventDefault();    
     .......    
}
```

But after that, the links can't response to click event any more.

Comment: I have fix it myself. Just like MDN said: it's common to call preventDefault() on touchmove rather than touchstart. That way, mouse events can still fire and things like links will continue to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you basically took away the "default behavior" of the document. Is there a reason why you have that in your code. You are adding it to the whole document.

Don't put the addEventListener on your whole document, put it on an element within the document.

Comment: First, I need a function when I touch and move on the screen, the document can scroll to the right position. But I have some links at this document, these links's default behavior shouldn't be canceled!

Answer (score 0):

`evt.preventDefault();` removes the events default behaviour. If you click a button which default action is to propagate the link, the `preventDefault();` will prevent this from happening.